# why is django not recognizing my admin user/password when i try to log in?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-admin

here is what i did:

```
> python manage.py createsuperuser
Username (Leave blank to use 'joe'): admin
E-mail address: random_email@yahoo.com
Password:
Password (again):
Superuser created successfully.
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mkstemp'" in <bound method DatastoreFileStub.__del__ of <google.appengine.api.datastore_file_stub
.DatastoreFileStub object at 0x02928470>> ignored

> python manage.py shell
[1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User
[2]: users = User.objects.all()
[3]: users
[3]: [<User: admin>]
[4]: users[0].set_password('password')
[5]: users[0].save()
[6]: exit()
Exeption AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mkstemp'" in <bound method DatastoreFileStub.__del__ of <google.appengine.api.datastore_file_stub
tastoreFileStub object at 0x028D9490>> ignored

> python manage.py syncbd
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
No fixtures found.
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mkstemp'" in <bound method DatastoreFileStub.__del__ of <google.appengine.api.datastore_file_stub
.DatastoreFileStub object at 0x02A83310>> ignored

> python manage.py validate
0 errors found
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mkstemp'" in <bound method DatastoreFileStub.__del__ of <google.appengine.api.datastore_file_stub
.DatastoreFileStub object at 0x028A3310>> ignored
```

when i try to log in: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/, it keeps saying that the user/pass conbination is wrong. is there any specific files i need to enable admin page?

Comment: Looks like a problem with your DB settings.

Comment: @agf my "leader" set this django project up and he doesnt even know how to fix it, guess he probably stole it somewhere... thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what agf said in his comment, it looks to be a db setting issue. There's a difference between what's defined in your models and what's defined in the db.

Check to see if you've ran `./manage.py syncdb` or what happens when you run `./manage.py validate`?

**Update Based on Comment**

> App Engine does not support Django models. You have to write your
>   models using App Engine's db.models or ndb.models API.

See this link: [data is stored on localhost but not on gae datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327151/data-is-stored-on-localhost-but-not-on-gae-datastore)

Comment: this is what i get from syncdb: Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
No fixtures found.
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mkstemp'" in
.DatastoreFileStub object at 0x028C3310>> ignored

Comment: are you using django or django-nonrel?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the 1.6.4 SDK, there's a bug where the database doesn't save on exit().

I believe this is fixed on 1.6.5.

Comment: where can i check for the version? i think my team "leader" probably just copy paste someone else's work...

Comment: Actually, I've heard that it's still broken on 1.6.5 (haven't confirmed myself).  See this question for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060172/gae-sdk-1-6-4-dev-appserver-datastore-flush

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, `users[0]` does not make the whole `QuerySet` evaluated and cached. You need to evaluate whole `QuerySet` or assign `users[0]` to some variable and use the variable:

```
>>> users[0] is users[0]
False
>>> user = users[0]
>>> user is user
True
>>> len(users); users[0] is users[0]
True
```

leader难当啊～